# Accessing another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, viewcontroller

I'm trying to access some things from another viewcontroller (iOS).

I have my ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    ...
}

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   ViewController2.someVar = @"cakes"; // this is where I'm trying to set something in vc2
}
```

ViewController2.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
{
   ...
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *someVar;

@end
```

ViewController2.m:

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

@synthesize someVar;

etc.
```

But at the line where I try to access this var, it gives me the following error:

Property 'someVar' not found on object of type 'ViewController2'.

In what way would I achieve accessing this other view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a `ViewControlle2` object in your `Viewcontroller.m`.

```
ViewController2 *myVC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
myVC2.someVar = @"cakes";
```

Comment: Ok it sort of works. When I NSLog the var in VC1 like myVC2.var, it shows, which is great.
But when I NSLog it from VC2, its empty again!

Comment: @Cake, where did you log it in VC2?

Comment: viewDidLoad. But I don't see why that would matter :/

Comment: @Cake: If you log it in both places, what order do you see them in? And are you creating your ViewController2 in the nib, in code, or both?

Comment: you have to log "self.someVar", not only "someVar".

Comment: @JJSaccolo: Since Cake is explicitly synthesizing the property, the synthesized instance variable has the same name. `someVar` and `self.someVar` do mean different things, but, in this context (retrieval, not assignment) and without an override implementation of `-someVar`, they are effectively equivalent. Accessing the property (`self.someVar`) would be more proper, but would not solve the problem.

Comment: @PeterHosey yes, correct. Sorry, I didn't see the `@synthesize`. So, I think that the problem is how you (@Cake) are creating and showing the `ViewController2`. You should show the `myVC2` object after its creation. For example, if you're using a `UINavigationController` you should push `myVC2` with `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC2];`.

Comment: Can't check the order right now since I'm not at home, but I created the biggest part of it in the interface builder. And I think that is indeed what the problem could be, that there is no link between the VC2 object and the actual ViewController2 where the data should be loaded into.

Comment: @Cake: If you created the view controller in a nib, then you are correct: Creating it once in the nib and once in the code will create two ViewController2s. You more probably want to add an outlet and connect it to the one in the nib.

Comment: Ok I'm trying to create an IBOutlet for the viewcontroller2 in viewcontroller, so I can access it. I add this to VC.h:  
IBOutlet ViewController2 *myVC2;  
But I can't link it to anything in the storyboard

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is by using delegates.  If you created ViewController1 in AppDelegate, you should also create ViewController2 in AppDelegate, or where ever you create your ViewControllers.  Then you ViewController1 would send a message to AppDelegate to get the data from ViewController2 and vice versa.  This makes ViewController1 and ViewController2 no longer dependent on each other.

So in AppDelegate.h we'd have something like this

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <MyViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) ViewController1 *viewController1;
@property (nonatomic) ViewController2 *viewController2;

@end
```

Then in both view controllers you can add this line in the .h

```
@property (nonatomic) id<MyViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

This just gives us a variable to use to refer to the delegate from within the ViewController's .m

You also need to create the MyViewControllerDelegate protocol, so in a file called MyViewControllerDelegate.h

```
@protocol MyViewControllerDelegate

- (ViewController1 *) viewController1;

- (ViewControlelr2 *) viewController2;

@end
```

Then when you create the ViewControllers in AppDelegate.m, you should also set AppDelegate as the ViewController's delegate.

```
self.viewController1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
self.viewController1.delegate = self;
self.viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
self.viewController2.delegate = self;
```

So with all of this delegate set up done, you should be able to access viewController2.someVar from viewController1 through the delegate by using:

```
self.delegate.viewController2.someVar = @"Cakes";
```

Hope this isn't too long winded.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Enigma. Since I'm not advanced-leveled in Cocoa yet, I do have some questions:
- Is this a better way to solve it, using a delegate class to control both viewcontrollers?
- I wasn't sure about the definition of 'delegation', so I checked Apple's description on it. Here is what's in there:

"in a garbage-collected environment, the receiver maintains a strong reference to its delegate"

Wikipedia says: 

"a weak reference is a reference that does not protect the referenced object from collection by a garbage collector".

Aren't these 2 opposite statements? I'm lost :P

Comment: In this case we're using a delegate as a data source, which is a bit different.  At the bottom of [the apple developer page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html), they talk a little about that.  It also talks about delegates in general, which you may find helpful.  I usually end up using them sort of like interfaces in a language like JAVA, so the view controller delegates the body of one of its more generic functions to its delegate, rather than defining it itself.

Comment: As far as if this is a good solution, I almost always implement it this way just because it separates the view controllers from the data.  So if you remove one of your view controllers or drastically change it later on in your project, you don't have to totally change how your information gets stored, it just lives in the delegate and is still accessible for the other controllers.

Comment: Thanks. And about your solution, how is MyViewControllerDelegate.h supposed to look? Because - (ViewController1 *) viewController1; will give me an error "Missing context for method declaration".

Comment: Make sure that you include the `@protocol` and `@end`.  I think that should help.  Also make sure you include the headers for your classes at the top of the protocol.